# Error: [function] is not defined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm getting an undefined function error that for the life of me I can't figure out. What is wrong with this script?

```
var numnames=0;
var names=new Array();
function SortNames(){
thename=document.theform.newname.value;
numnames++;
names.sort();
document.theform.sorted.value=names.join("\n");
}
```

I call the code here:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script type="text/javscript" language="javascript" src="sort.js">
</script>
<h1>Sorting Array</h1>
<p>Enter two or more names in the field below, and the sorted list of names will appear in the text area<p>
<form name=theform>
Name:
<input type=text name=newname size=20>
<input type=button name=addname value=Add onclick="SortNames();">
<br/>
<h2>Sorted Names</h2>
<textarea cols=60 rows=10 name=sorted>
The sorted names will appear here
</textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I get is `SortNames is not defined`.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but the name should be initialized with the var keyword, unless it's defined elsewhere. What's the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: When you ask a question, post the exact error that you are given. After all, you're here because you're not sure why your error is occuring.

Comment: Post more code, your problem might not be in the code you listed. Where do you actually call SortNames?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you try changing:

```
<script type="text/javscript" language="javascript" src="sort.js">
```

To

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="sort.js">
```

?

And check if your browser can find sort.js using the debugger.

Comment: Just a tip: Using `<script src="sort.js"></script>` is slightly better because the script tag implies it is JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, either you are using an older browser or the error is in another part of your code. Try to reduce your file to the bare minimum needed to test or use the javascript console to track down other errors.